# Web Scraper Behind Authentication

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

I am a novice programmer trying to accelerate the data analysis process by automating the conversion of .ict files to .csv files.

I am trying to create a Python program that easily converts .ict files from NASA's Earthdata Website into .csv files for data analysis. I am planning on doing this by creating a data scraper to access these files, but they are behind a user authentication wall.  The data sets I am planning on accessing are found at this link:
https://asdc.larc.nasa.gov/data/AJAX/O3_1/2018/02/28/AJAX-O3_ALPHA_20180228_R1_F220.ict

Here is the code that I collected from https://curlconverter.com/# and added to send the data to "log in" my session:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {
    '_ga': '',
    '_gid': '',
    '_gat_GSA_ENOR0': '1',
    '_gat_UA-62340125-1': '1',
    '_gat_eui_tracker': '1',
    '_gat_UA-50960810-3': '1',
    '_urs-gui_session': '',
    '_gat_UA-62340125-2': '1',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': '',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=OLpAZlE4HqIOMr0TYqg7UQ&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fd53njncz5taqi.cloudfront.net%2Furs_callback&state=https%3A%2F%2Fsearch.earthdata.nasa.gov%2Fsearch%3Fee%3Dprod',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

data = {
  'utf8': '',
  'authenticity_token': '',
  'username': '',
  'password': '',
  'client_id': '',
  'redirect_uri': '',
  'response_type': 'code',
  'state': 'https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search?ee=prod',
  'stay_in': '1',
  'commit': 'Log in'
}

response = requests.post('https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/login', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)


s = requests.Session()
s.post('https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/login', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
response = s.get("https://asdc.larc.nasa.gov/data/AJAX/O3_1/2018/02/28/AJAX-O3_ALPHA_20180228_R1_F220.ict")
response
result = requests.get('https://asdc.larc.nasa.gov/data/AJAX/O3_1/2018/02/28/AJAX-O3_ALPHA_20180228_R1_F220.ict')
result.status_code
result.headers
content = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features='lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

This print function leads me to the HTML code for the login page.  Does anyone know how to access the data on the other end of the login through Python?

Comment: Have you tried the `allow_redirects` flag with your POST request when submitting the log in form?

Comment: I updated the line ```response = requests.post('https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/login', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data, allow_redirects=True)```, but the program still directs to the log in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things missing in your `data`, as in the value of `authenticity_token` and encoded value of `state`. The following is how I would do it. Make sure to fill in the `username` and `password` fields accordingly before executing the script.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize?splash=false&client_id=iQGRa5KtDl_e-fgYqB5x5Q&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fasdc.larc.nasa.gov%2Fdata%2Furs&state=aHR0cDovL2FzZGMubGFyYy5uYXNhLmdvdi9kYXRhL0FKQVgvTzNfMS8yMDE4LzAyLzI4L0FKQVgtTzNfQUxQSEFfMjAxODAyMjhfUjFfRjIyMC5pY3Q'
link = 'https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/login'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['username'] = 'your_username'
    payload['password'] = 'your_password'
    res = s.post(link,data=payload)
    print(res.text)
```

Comment: I entered this into my Jupyter Lab session and in this current setup, it returned the authentication code to show that I had successfully logged in.  To access the data behind the authentication page, I added the line: ```res = s.get(url)``` after the current ```res``` variable, which gave me access to the data I needed.  Thank you so much!